Receive sharing intent not receiving media in Flutter
I need my flutter app to receive media(image/pdf etc) from external applications. I tried using receive_sharing_intent.
From my manifest:
            <!--For receiving media from external applications-->  
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
              </intent-filter>
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
              </intent-filter>
        </activity>

and:
  late StreamSubscription _intentSub;
  final _sharedFiles = <SharedMediaFile>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Listen to media sharing coming from outside the app while the app is in the memory.
    _intentSub = ReceiveSharingIntent.instance.getMediaStream().listen((value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedFiles.clear();
        _sharedFiles.addAll(value);

        print(_sharedFiles.map((f) => f.toMap()));
      });
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getIntentDataStream error: $err");
    });

    // Get the media sharing coming from outside the app while the app is closed.
    ReceiveSharingIntent.instance.getInitialMedia().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedFiles.clear();
        _sharedFiles.addAll(value);
        print(_sharedFiles.map((f) => f.toMap()));

        // Tell the library that we are done processing the intent.
        ReceiveSharingIntent.instance.reset();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _intentSub.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),
        child: HomeAppBar(),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ..._sharedFiles.map((f) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(" path ${f.path}"),
              subtitle: Text(f.type.value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

But I am not getting anything inside the body. I need android only and I am pretty sure I handled all the configuration correctly.
Flutter version: 3.22.0

I tried to run your code and it's working as expected. At first the screen is blank then I share some image/video from gallery app then the path is visible inside the body.
